# ¿Cómo ejecutar una Tarea en Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Esta es la tarea que tengo que ejecutar, debería generarme un token, he intentado con `rake Config:set_token` y no funciona, me muestra este error:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Secret should not be nil.
/home/techsystems/Projects/ts_fiscal_api/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:54:in new'
/home/techsystems/Projects/ts_fiscal_api/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:54:in encrypt'
/home/techsystems/Projects/ts_fiscal_api/lib/tasks/set_token.rake:5:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/techsystems/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/bundle:23:in load'
/home/techsystems/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => Config:set_token
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Config.rake:

```
namespace :Config do
  desc "Establecer token de seguridad"

  task set_token: :environment do
    include ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper

    secret_token = encrypt(ENV['cadena'])
    token_key = Config.find_by_key('token')

    if token_key != nil
      token_key.update(value:secret_token)
    else
      Config.create(key:'token',value:secret_token)
    end

    puts secret_token
  end
end
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no funciona?, ¿te muestra algún error?, ¿cuál?

Comment: Este error aparece: rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Secret should not be nil.
/home/techsystems/Projects/ts_fiscal_api/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:54:in `new'
/home/techsystems/Projects/ts_fiscal_api/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:54:in `encrypt'
/home/techsystems/Projects/ts_fiscal_api/lib/tasks/set_token.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/techsystems/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/techsystems/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => Config:set_token
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las variables de ambiente definidas en tu aplicación no están disponibles en las tareas *rake*, por lo tanto el método `encrypt(ENV['cadena'])` está recibiendo `nil` como argumento.

Para que tu código funcione debes asignar el valor a la variable al ejecutar la tarea; por ejemplo:

```
rake Config:set_token cadena=valor_de_variable
```

Comment: Gracias! si funcionó